# Can't create SqlParameter in EF Core 3.1.2 in Xamarin.Android application

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have Android Xamarin.Forms project. It depends on `Db` project with EF Core code (SQL Server) and targeted .Net Standard 2.0. Both projects in one solution.

With EF Core 2.2.6 everything works fine. When I switch to EF Core 3.1.2, the project does not work anymore.

I made the following changes to compile it:

- I added `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.1.1` nuget project reference and use namespace `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`
- Replace `DbSet<Entitiy>.FromSql` calls with `DbSet<Entitiy>.FromSqlRaw`

When I create `SqlParameter` and try to access it I get an error.

E.g. when I run the following code:

```
try
{
    var sqlParam = new SqlParameter("aaa", "bbb");
    var value = sqlParam.Value; // exception thrown here
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.GetType()}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
}
```

I get the following error messages:

> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   StackTrace:   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.get_Value () [0x00000] in E:\SqlClientInternal\agent-1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
>   etcore\ref\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.cs:1222
>   at  [0x00012] in .cs:100

When the `sqlParam` just assigned, and I want to view its value, I get the following view in Visual Studio:

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2019, I tried 16.3.4 and the latest as for now 16.4.6.

How to fix this issue? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Based on `SqlParameter("aaa", "bbb");` and your error message, please make sure you have `aaa` colum in your table and your could refer to this link about usage of this class:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT  `SqlParameter("aaa", "bbb")` is for testing only, there is no `aaa` column. But `SqlParameter` instance is not related to a specific table, I don't think that it is important in my example above to have `aaa` column. Anyway, I got the same error for correct values of parameters, which are used to call stored procedures. Everything worked in `EF Core 2.2.6`, but stopped working just after switch to .`EF Core 3.1.2`. "aaa" is used just for simplicity